# WEB API service call in D3.js to make circle packing

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

first I have made this Web API from where I am getting tree structure object.

```
private TreeService _studentServices = new TreeService();

    private static List<TreeNode> FillRecursive(ICollection<SalaryDetail> flatObjects, int? Refid = null)
    {
        return flatObjects.Where(x => x.Refid.Equals(Refid)).Select(item => new TreeNode
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            Id = item.Id,
            Salary = item.Salary,
            Refid = item.Refid,

            Children = FillRecursive(flatObjects, item.Id)
        }).ToList();
    }
    // GET api/values
    public List<TreeNode> Get()
    {
        ICollection<SalaryDetail> salarydetails = _studentServices.GetAllSalaryDetails();

        var tree = FillRecursive(salarydetails, null);


        return tree;

    }
```

then I called This API in D3 as given below to show the data as a D3.js circle packing graph.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/d3js/3.5.16/d3.js"></script>
    <script>



        var diameter = 700,
        format = d3.format(",d");

        var pack = d3.layout.pack()
            .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
            .value(function (d) { return d.salary; });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", diameter)
            .attr("height", diameter)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(2,2)");

        d3.json("http://localhost:56935/api/values", function (error, root) {

            var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
                        .data(pack.nodes)
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", function (d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
                        .attr("transform", function (d) {
                            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                        });

            node.append("title")
            .text(function (d) { return d.name + (d.children ? "" : ": " + format(d.salary)); });

            node.append("circle")
                .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; });

            node.filter(function (d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".3em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3); })
                .style("font-size", 20);
        });

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Although I am getting data through D3.json() function but not my circle packing graph, Not even getting single error. Please help me out to make these graph. where am I lacking.

The structure of the json returning by Web Api is given below

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"James","Salary":null,"Refid":null,"Children":[{"Id":2,"Name":"David","Salary":null,"Refid":1,"Children":[{"Id":3,"Name":"Richard","Salary":null,"Refid":2,"Children":[{"Id":4,"Name":"John","Salary":1000,"Refid":3,"Children":[]},{"Id":5,"Name":"Robert","Salary":4000,"Refid":3,"Children":[]},{"Id":6,"Name":"Paul","Salary":6000,"Refid":3,"Children":[]}]},{"Id":7,"Name":"Kevin","Salary":null,"Refid":2,"Children":[{"Id":8,"Name":"Jason","Salary":5000,"Refid":7,"Children":[]},{"Id":9,"Name":"Mark","Salary":null,"Refid":7,"Children":[{"Id":10,"Name":"Thomas","Salary":1000,"Refid":9,"Children":[]},{"Id":11,"Name":"Donald","Salary":1000,"Refid":9,"Children":[]}]}]}]}]}]
```

Comment: can you post the structure of the json you are receiving?

Comment: @iulian I have just posted the json structure

Comment: Dear anonymous user, did my answer below helped you?

Comment: @iulian yes, helped me a lot. thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Do you mind marking it as the accepted answer? So that other people who face the same problem know that this solution works. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of returning a `List` at your endpoint, return an object (the first element from your current returning list). From [D3 docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#nodes) for pack layout:

> the input argument to the layout is the root node of the hierarchy

2. Either rename the `Children -> children` property name (by default `D3` expects hierarchical data to be under `children` key), or define a different key for your data like this:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
        .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
        .value(function (d) { return d.Salary; }) // Note that according to your data structure, your `Salary` should start with a capital letter.
        .children(function (d) { return d.Children; }); // Define how to obtain children data.
```